# Conditionally prevent event removal depending on the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an interesting situation. I have multiple click events attached to an element.

After event 1, I need to remove event 2, but keep event 1.

Here is what I have:

```
$('.square').on('click', grow);
$('.square').on('click', nameReset);
var nameReset = function () {
    alert(this.className);
}
var grow = function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('grow');
    $(this).off('click');
}
```

In other words, I need to keep the grow function, but remove nameReset after the event is fired.

```
.square {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display :inline-block;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.grow {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- Either specify the function when you remove the event (i.e., `$(this).off('click', nameReset)`).

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w94zf3La/)

  > [**jQuery `.off()`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
  >
  > A handler can be removed by specifying the function name in the handler argument. When jQuery attaches an event handler, it assigns a unique id to the handler function.

  ```
  var nameReset = function () {
      alert(this.className);
  }
  var grow = function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('grow');
      $(this).off('click', nameReset);
  }
  $('.square').on('click', grow);
  $('.square').on('click', nameReset);
  ```
- Alternatively, you could [namespace the events](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), (`$(this).off('click.square.nameReset')`) in order to remove the desired event:

  [**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5642xjz/)

  ```
  var nameReset = function () {
      alert(this.className);
  }
  var grow = function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('grow');
      $(this).off('click.square.nameReset');
  }

  $('.square').on('click.square.grow', grow);
  $('.square').on('click.square.nameReset', nameReset);
  ```